# How to work with custom xml in PowerPoint and office.js?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

In `Word` you can use the `Office.context.document.customXmlParts` API to get access to custom xml. In `Excel` you have to use `Excel.run((context) => {})` and can then use `context.workbook.customXmlParts` for the same purpose.

How can you do this in `PowerPoint` using `office.js`?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not yet implemented for PowerPoint. However we are actively working on improving PowerPoint OfficeJS API surface, it is possible that there might be some news on this specific API in the upcoming months.

Comment: Sounds good. Can you share anything about why this is the case? I'm thinking there are different teams that might not be in touch? For example, why isn't custom xml handled by a shared api between Word, Excel and PowerPoint? Is custom xml handled differently on different applications?

Comment: There were different priorities for the teams in the last few years, PowerPoint's OfficeJS API surface was a bit behind compared to other Apps. Although some API implementation can be shared between apps, the apps require some infrastructure work to make it happen, actually there are some new set of APIs that is started to appear for PowerPoint recently ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/powerpoint-preview-apis ). CustomXml support is one of the main requirements for addins, which I believe might come sometime in the near future.

Comment: What about custom document properties (text/number)? Btw, feel free to reach out to me if you need any specific testing. I'm using office.js rather extensively and don't mind running bleeding edge.

Comment: Custom properties are also similar, we would need to add support on PowerPoint. However I believe that might have a lower priority than CustomXml in my opinion, as custom xml might be much more powerful for the addins. And thanks ralphtheninja, I'll definitely keep the offer in mind :)

Comment: @OnurOnder have there been any updates since November? I am working on a project that intends to pop up a pane whenever a user inserts an image. That pane would provide a more detailed guide on how to write alt text--and ideally allow the user to write alt text right in that plugin panel. Any guide, idea, or API you think we should explore would be extremely happy. Our target is the newer JS plugin for powerpoint but are open to change

Comment: @TheNorthWes, at this time, the underlying implementation is almost complete but it is not publicly available yet. Tags API is also alternative to customXml, but it is more limited.

Comment: Fwiw, I managed to get around this by reading the file data and using js-zip and manually editing the customXml file